# Does the Visual Studio code extension API allow the modification of tabs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to write an extension that allows you to group together multiple tabs that could be cycled through, perhaps just by repeatedly clicking. I find that when working on Angular components for example that I have the .ts, .html and .less files of the component open at once and I'd like to keep them together. In this case those 3 files could all be kept under 1 tab in the editor that you could just cycle through.

Does anyone with some experience writing VS code extensions know whether this can be done? Nothing I've seen in the docs seems to quite fit.